# Numerical integration of a rapidly varying complex exponential

Tags: numerics, integral-equations

I have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ and I wish to numerically evaluate the integral below over a finite domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

$$
I = \int_\Omega e^{i k \cdot f(\mathbf{x})} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}
$$

where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a **large** positive real constant, for example typically $k \approx 10^9$. The function $f$ is bounded over the domain of integration, and is continuous almost everywhere but does have some discontinuities. It is pretty smooth (qualitatively speaking) with gentle variation over its domain and no sharp peaks. In my particular case I know that

$$
0 < f(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0.1
$$

I write it this way to show that there is not much variation in the function itself, and the size of the $k$ parameter is the issue.

I am also able to obtain exact values for $f$ for various points in its domain, but there is no closed-form expression for it.

---

I am struggling to find a viable way to numerically evaluate $I$. The best way I found was to break up the 2D domain of integration into a mesh of small triangles, evaluate the function at each vertex and integrate piecewise using a linear approximation of the function over each triangle using barycentric interpolation. This works really well for moderate $k$ but as $k$ becomes large it starts requiring far too many triangles to get a good result. I suspect this is because the linear approximation needs to be extremely accurate for it to "survive" the complex exponential, and of course the error increases as $k$ grows.

Are there known methods of numerical integration that "work well" with problems of this form, or are they inherently difficult? What are some things I could try?

Comment: Can we identify subdomains where the function f(x) is smooth? Is the number of such domains finite?

Comment: Have you tried Levin- or Filon-type methods for highly oscillatory quadrature?

Comment: When you say "integrate piecewise using a linear approximation of the function", do you mean the f function or the whole integrand function?

Comment: @Rigel The $f$ function itself, not the integrand

Comment: @cos_theta I have not, but this gives me quite a bit of material to read on with the "highly oscillatory" keywords, thanks! I'll do some reading and try to understand their methods and see if/how they can be applied to my case

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that the function does not vary much because it is between zero and 0.1. If your function corresponds to masses and you measure your function in terms of "multiples of the mass of the supermassive black hole at the center of the galaxy", then pretty much anything that has mass will have mass between 0 and 0.1. The only reasonable measure for "a function does not vary very much" is if the ratio of its largest to the its smallest value is close to one.

Comment: Highly oscillatory integrals are not necessarily difficult. In fact, because they
oscillate and converge they can be quite easy using the appropriate tools.
Prof. Arieh Iserles web page lists many papers he has published on the topic.
http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ai/Arieh_Iserles/Papers.html

This one would be a good start.
A. Iserles & S.P. Nørsett, "On quadrature methods for highly oscillatory integrals and their implementation", BIT 44 (2004), 755–772.

Comment: @Lysistrata: A concise summary would be interesting.

Comment: @A rural reader
Here's a snippet from the paper...
Therefore – and this might come as a surprise to all those conditioned by
the urban legend that highly oscillatory problems are difficult to compute –
the quality of these methods increases in tandem with oscillation. Indeed, we
can make this improvement in precision arbitrarily large by using derivative
information at designated points.

Comment: Techniques such as exponential "fade-factors", and "artificial viscosity" can also be used on some highly oscillatory integrals. See for example:

E.O. Tuck, S.I. Collins, and W. Wells: On ship wave patterns and their spectra, March 1971, J. Ship Research.

E.O. Tuck, D. Scullen, L. Lazauskas: Wave Patterns and Minimum Wave Resistance for High-Speed Vessels, 
    
Both methods are discussed in my thesis:
L. Lazauskas, Resistance, wave-making and wave-decay of thin ships, with emphasis on the effects of viscosity. https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/handle/2440/53216